# Выбрать нужный Selector в Android?

Tags: android

Всем привет! Есть такой селектор.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_s"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item1
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_s"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button"/>
</selector>
```

Работает все нормально. Но только в Drawable я могу описать внешний вид, а текст шрифта описать не могу. Мне нужные что бы на неактивный был один цвет шрифта, а на активной другой!

Comment: боюсь, что из селектора нельзя изменить цвет шрифта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).

**res/color/green_button_text_color.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#0d800d"/>
    <item android:color="#00ff00"/>
</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="@color/green_button_text_color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```